# Process Manager for JULIA

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia. I am looking for a **Process Manager** for It, specifically for Genie Apps. (In the other words, something equivalent to PM2 for Node.JS). Could anyone help please?

Comment: Or maybe PM2 itself can run Genie apps. If so, Could anyone describe how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adrian here, creator of Genie.

I haven't used PM2 but I have used supervisord and I presume they are similar in their approach. Genie apps run in Julia processes which are regular OS processes. What have you tried and what issues have you encountered?

Fiddled a bit with `pm2` and the process seems to be straightforward. I'm sure it can be improved by setting up more complex `pm2` configuration files, but for a quick solution, this seems to do the trick.

I'm on a windows machine so I confirmed it to work on both Win 10 and WSL/Ubuntu. Let's say we have a Genie app called MyGenieApp, then we run:

Windows PowerShell:

```
PS C:\MyGenieApp\bin> pm2 start cmd -- -- /k .\server.bat
```

This will open a CMD window and start the Genie app with the parent `cmd` process under `pm2` control.

WSL/Ubuntu

```
(MyGenieApp) $ pm2 start bash -- bin/server
```

Should work the same as WSL for macOS and other *nix OS.

- Notice that for Windows you need run it from within `bin/` while for *nix from the app's folder (so one level higher, in `../bin`). You can edit the files to adjust the paths as needed.
- For some reason, on windows, `pm2` needs `-- --` otherwise it does not pass the arguments to the script. Might a bug in `pm2`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am using PM2 on Ubuntu and it seems it is working perfectly for Genie apps too. I have just started .SH file in bin folder using PM2.